# Как сделать многоуровневое меню в navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Для такого меню мне нужно сделать чтобы у меню было несколько уровней. Чтобы при нажатии на Home раскрывались внизу еще пункты меню или может быть есть более красивые варианты. Подскажите пожалуйста где искать а то не могу нигде найти хотя бы примерно как это делать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для истории на будущее: как выяснилось в процессе работы, спиннер совершенно сюда не подходит, для многоуровнего меню получилось использовать эту библиотеку https://github.com/sunil676/NavigationViewAndroid

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой и удобный вариант, сделать **кастомный макет** меню. В отличии от использования библиотек, в таком меню не будет никаких ограничений в сложности реализации. Всегда можно что-то сдвинуть/поменять, да и меньше лишнего кода.

Просто делаете обычный макет и размещаете в **NavigationView**.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_task_list">

        <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_menu"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Чтобы меню получилось в стиле **Material Design**, смотрите инфо [здесь](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#). Там описаны все его размеры и особенности.

Вот один из примеров реализации кастомного меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо! в следующий раз попробую

Comment: Интересный, но малосодержательно